# Once they opened it

Tags: grammaticality

Is "once they opened it" correct in this sentence?

Then, suddenly, someone knocked on the door and once they opened it, they said: "I've finally found you!"

Answer (score 1):

If the person who knocked is the same person who opened the door, the sentence makes sense.

If they were not, you might replace it with:

> Someone knocked on the door, and once it opened they said...